# How can I change the status of an application to a bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I would like to know how I can change a state that I have initialized in a widget to a bloc to handle it globally

```
final AssetsAudioPlayer _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
  final List<StreamSubscription> _subscriptions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _subscriptions.add(_assetsAudioPlayer.playlistFinished.listen((data) {
      print("finished : $data");
    }));
    _subscriptions.add(_assetsAudioPlayer.playlistAudioFinished.listen((data) {
      print("playlistAudioFinished : $data");
    }));
    _subscriptions.add(_assetsAudioPlayer.current.listen((data) {
      print("current : $data");
    }));
    _subscriptions.add(_assetsAudioPlayer.onReadyToPlay.listen((audio) {
      print("onRedayToPlay : $audio");
    }));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _assetsAudioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I think the code is incomplete, can you share how are you using bloc here?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough code here to understand in detail what you are looking for, but...

My suggestion is looking at the documentation for [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) which provides data globally and dynamically to your widgets.

There is also [Flutter_Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) which is the preferred library for most people who have adopted BLOC pattern.

Both packages have good examples to get you started.